# Plot daily level data but with only monthly level labels

Tags: python, seaborn

Given data that comes in this format:

```
d = {'date_utc': [01 01, 01 02, 02 03, 02 22, 03 05, 04 20], 'total_green': [3.0, 7.0, 10.0, 14.0, 2.0, 8.0]}
dfTime = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dfTime

date_utc      total_green
01 01         3.0
01 02         7.0
02 03         10.0
02 22         14.0
03 05          2.0
04 20          8.0
```

I want to plot this over time with the unit of analysis on the graph being daily but the label of the x axis to be month "Jan", "Feb", etc.

Current Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (40, 15))
sns.lineplot(data=dfTime, linewidth=2.5)


# Customize the axes and title
ax.set_title("Green Words used on Instagram over Time", fontsize = 26)
ax.set_xlabel("Time", fontsize = 18)
ax.set_ylabel("Green Words", fontsize = 18)



plt.show()
```

I ultimately want something that looks like this: [image]

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it??

Comment: You can try setting xticks to a list of months. Note that length of current xticks and new xticks should match

Comment: @Harsh example code would be helpful.

Comment: please provide daily sample data at least over a couple of months

Comment: @DavidErickson updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert your `date_utc` to `datetime` before plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

current_year = '2020'
d = {'date_utc': ['01 01', '01 02', '02 03', '02 22', '03 05', '04 20'], 'total_green': [3.0, 7.0, 10.0, 14.0, 2.0, 8.0]}
d['date_utc'] = [np.datetime64('-'.join((current_year + ' ' + m).split(' '))) for m in d['date_utc']]
#d = {'date_utc': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-22', '2020-03-05', '2020-04-20'], 'total_green': [3.0, 7.0, 10.0, 14.0, 2.0, 8.0]}
#d['date_utc'] = [np.datetime64(m) for m in d['date_utc']]

dfTime = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

months = mdates.MonthLocator()
days = mdates.DayLocator()
months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (40, 15))
sns.lineplot(data=dfTime, linewidth=2.5, x="date_utc", y="total_green")

# format the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)

# Customize the axes and title
ax.set_title("Green Words used on Instagram over Time", fontsize = 26)
ax.set_xlabel("Time", fontsize = 18)
ax.set_ylabel("Green Words", fontsize = 18)

plt.show()
```

Reference:

[Date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)

[strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

[image]